# CannonJS lock rotation on specific axes

Tags: javascript, rotation, collision-detection, cannon.js

I have seen the [CannonJS FPS Demo](https://schteppe.github.io/cannon.js/examples/threejs_fps.html) and noticed that it used a sphere for player collisions. My character is not in a form of a sphere, but rather a box or a capsule.

I have tried using a box for collisions, but I cannot seem to [lock the rotation](https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js/issues/46) on the X or Z axis setting `inertia` or `angularFactor`. When using `fixedRotation`, it does lock the rotation all axes but causes the movement to be severely restricted. When using a box shape with no restrictions, the box starts to tumble around when moving.

How would I go about keeping the player upright by locking rotation on the X and Z axes?

Answer (score 2):

Just set angularDamping to one on init with:

```
playerBody.angularDamping = 1;
```

then in the animation/movement part use at the rotation key handler:

```
playerBody.angularDamping = 0;
```

But dont forget to set it every loop at the beginning back to 1. FixedRotation seems to just prevent something. I try to understand that by myself too:
[Here you can read more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43293351/cannon-js-sliding-effect)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to only lock specific axes, you can use [`Body.angularFactor`](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/Body.html#angularFactor). For instance, if you want the body to only rotate around the Y axis you can do

```js
const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
body.angularFactor = new CANNON.Vec3(0, 1, 0);
```

If you want *all* axes to be locked, you can use [`Body.fixedRotation`](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/docs/classes/Body.html#fixedRotation) as can be seen in [this demo](https://pmndrs.github.io/cannon-es/examples/fixed_rotation):

```js
const body = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 1 });
body.fixedRotation = true;
```